# How to solve this problem "Thymeleaf Plugin ERROR in STS"?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf, sts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA9AC.png)

`

`

always show this above error when I dowload thymeleaf plugin in my sts.
please help me...
how to remove this error?
`

`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sun.xml.bind,2.2.0.v201505121915 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,jakarta.activation-api,1.2.2 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javaewah,1.1.6.v20160919-1400 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.contentassist.feature,3.0.1.202109120458 No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.contentassist.feature.source,3.0.1.202109120458 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.contentassist.source,3.0.1.202109120458 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.thymeleaf.extras.eclipse.core.source,3.0.1.202109120458`

Comment: Reorganize your post properly, first explain your problem then share your source and error message as the plain text format. After that you can get help easily. Now it is so messy :(